# Calculate distance between similar pixels - Euclidean distance - ArcGIS 10.1 - Erdas Imagine

Tags: gis, arcgis, euclidean-distance

I have an unsigned 1-bit thematic forest cover raster (.img).  1 = forest and 0 = not forest.  I want to calculate the distance between forest patches.  It appears that the Euclidean Distance tool in ArcGIS does this but I get an output with all 0s.

Has anyone had experience with this before?  Am I doing something incorrectly?  Will I have to write a script to take care of it?

I can use either ArcGIS or Erdas Imagine.  Whichever is easiest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with a raster with values 0 and 1. Export your .img to .tiff with 8 bit unsigned and try it again.

Comment: You nailed it.  For some reason it was being picky with the .img file.